# What does F do in python flask before string?

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/<name>")
def office(name):
    return F"Hello {name}! "
```

What is the F doing before "Hello {name}! "?

Comment: They are f-strings, just google it https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Read about **f-strings** in Python3.

Comment: might https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ help you?

Answer (score 4):

These are called "f-strings" and are not limited to Flask. It's basically a string formatting mechanism used in Python.

Suppose you have a variable `name = "XYZ"`. Using

```
print ('Hello {name}')
```

will print "Hello {name}", which is not what you want. Instead, you use an f-string so you can have the value `{name}` be the same as your variable.

```
print (f'Hello {name}')
```

The above would print "Hello XYZ". Alternatively, you could also use the following:

```
print ('Hello {}'.format(name))
```

You can read about them in more detail here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/